# react component out of the css grid

Tags: css, reactjs, grid

I need to adjust the size of a carousel component (make it smaller). For this I use width in a css class but it doesn't work (in the css inspector of chrome it appears as commented). How could I do it?

grid.css

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    /* grid-gap: 10px; */
    grid-template-rows: minmax(300px, 500px) 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.carousel {
    width: 50%;
}
```

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Tournament from './Tournament.jsx'
import Carousel from './Carousel.jsx'
import '../resources/styles/grid.css'


const App = () => (
  <div className="wrapper">
      <Carousel className = "carousel"
        name='Copa de campeones'
        description=' Solo para los campeones de cada liga en su carrera'
        contact_name='Joaquin Cardenas'
        contact_number='+56951097841'
        date_tournament='2020-03-15'
        sport='Baby futbol'
      />

      <Tournament
        name='Copa de campeones'
        description=' Solo para los campeones de cada liga en su carrera'
        contact_name='Joaquin Cardenas'
        contact_number='+56951097841'
        date_tournament='2020-03-15'
        sport='Baby futbol'
      />
  </div >
)

export default App



'''
```

Answer (score 0):

The width rule as a percent has to be a percent of *something*, that something is a percentage of the parent element (if it has a defined width). You need to define a width on the containing div of the carousel.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-gap: 10px; */
  grid-template-rows: minmax(300px, 500px) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 400px; // give the parent element a defined width
  margin: auto; // you may need this to center the grid in whatever container *it* is in
}

.carousel {
    width: 50%; // this width is 50% of its parent, `wrapper` and will end up ~200px if the wrapper is ~400px
}
```

App.js

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <Carousel className = "carousel"
    name='Copa de campeones'
    description=' Solo para los campeones de cada liga en su carrera'
    contact_name='Joaquin Cardenas'
    contact_number='+56951097841'
    date_tournament='2020-03-15'
    sport='Baby futbol'
  />

  <Tournament
    name='Copa de campeones'
    description=' Solo para los campeones de cada liga en su carrera'
    contact_name='Joaquin Cardenas'
    contact_number='+56951097841'
    date_tournament='2020-03-15'
    sport='Baby futbol'
  />
</div >
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. This work for me, but my carousel It doesn't look 100% of its size, that is, it is cut. How can I make it have the same size as the row defined in my grid?

Comment: You likely want the `carousel` class to take 100% of the space allotted it by its containing wrapper, i.e. the wrapper defines the space the carousel is allowed to expand into.